# Is there a special name for this style of font?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

https://www.1001fonts.com/tostada-font.html

I quite like this font but I'm not 100% on it, I've searched for "alternatives to tostada font" but my searches don't come up with much. Is there a special name for this sort of font? I don't have the vocabulary to describe the style, it's serif but the bars(?) are invisible.

Failing that, do you know of any alternatives to this you could share with me?

Comment: Technically it's like it's made for stencils. I'm not at all sure would anyone who cuts painting stencils with a razor blade bother to make something this fine.. You find easily a little more coarse items for ex. in https://www.dafont.com Search for  stencil fonts.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: Could you please include an image of the font you're asking about in the question itself?

Answer (score 2):

It's a stencil font, basically, but the gaps are bigger than on most stencil faces and the horizontal strokes thicker. It's sort of like a Didone or modern face with the thin strokes deleted. Try "stencil Didone font" or "stencil modern serif". Commercial Type have a few fonts like this-[Dala is good](https://commercialtype.com/catalog/dala_floda), or [Dala Moa](https://commercialtype.com/catalog/dala_moa), or [Le Jeune](https://commercialtype.com/catalog/lejeune/lejeune_poster/stencil) is more of a modern but not as bold. Their [Dala Prisma](https://commercialtype.com/catalog/dala_prisma) isn't quite what you asked for but really amazing.

[image: Sample of Dala Moa font]